# API Access to Tesco personal purchases in store

Tags: python, jsonp, restful-url

Is there a programmatic (read Pythonic and/or RESTful) way to access Tesco Clubcard personal history and/or through a unique receipt token, for in store purchases?

It doesn't seem so from [this thread on Tesco Labs](http://www.tescolabs.com/?p=7171) and [TESCO API Documentation](https://secure.techfortesco.com/tescoapiweb/wiki/index.html)

Comment: Even not RESTFUL, there doesn't seem to be any way at the moment...